# why does UIColor colorWithHue:Sat:Brightness produce color with different hue as output?

Tags: iphone, ios, uicolor

Why does `+[UIColor colorWithHue:saturation:brightness]` produce color with different hue as output?

See my example below.  The hue input was **0.223404**, however the output looking at the color created was  **0.229560**

Test Code:

```
UIColor *uic = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.223404 saturation:0.944000 brightness:0.990291 alpha:1.0];
NSLog(@"Color Created:  %f, %f, %f", uic.hue, uic.saturation, uic.brightness);
```

Output:

```
Color Created:  0.229560, 0.944000, 0.990291
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably the nearest 24-bit RGB value (which is what the iPhone hardware can actually display) to your requested color.

Added: This looks closer to a 24-bit quantized HSV conversion from some underlying RGB value.  You might want to print out both the RGB and HSV to see which, if any, got quantized more.

Comment: Not the case, as Apple doesn't convert to 24-bit until drawing is done (as you can have 48-bit or higher target contexts.)

Answer (score 1):

Limited floating-point precision. While you typed `0.223404`, `0.229560` is the closest value that can be represented by a 32-bit floating-point number.

Comment: IEEE short floats are accurate to more than 6 decimal digits.  Whereas these two numbers differ in the 3rd decimal digit.

Comment: @Jonathan - any suggestions re how to wrok around? I've got a color picker view based on a Hue/Saturation picker image, and a Brightness Bar.  When you select a brightness it needs to update the currentColor instance variable, and for this I need to use UIColor's colorWithHue:saturation:brightness.  Perhaps this indicators a fundamental flaw with storing a color using UIColor then?

Comment: @hotpaw2 - would be interested in your commment to the "work around" question I just posed to Jonathan

Comment: PS as an example of a workaround - would one be to store separately hue/saturation/brightness as instance variables (as opposed to a CGColor)?  [not quite as nice has having a single variable to use as an ivar]

Comment: @hotpaw2 No, IEEE 32-bit floats have 6 decimal digits of precision. There are still values in that range they cannot exactly represent.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you store your floats because what you type is not what the compiler puts in the binary. Is there a reason you need such high precision?

Answer (score 1):

The hue/saturation/brightness will be transformed into RGBA values, and probably stored internally as CGFloat. I can only imagine that due to the nature of the transform, the hue is very sensitive to quantization error in this region. If you need higher accuracy, you'll probably have to create your own data type.